# flutter setState not updating showCupertinoDialog

Tags: flutter, setstate, showdialog

setState is not working in showCupertinoDialog. When i get async data i want to update the progress bar which is inside dialog. _progress value is updated and setstate is called successfully but dialog is not updating. I am using statefulBuilder.

```
 showCupertinoDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text("Preparing..."),
        content: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, StateSetter setState) {
          print('ssetstatte');
          return UploadIndicator(_progress);
        }),
        actions: [
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            isDefaultAction: true,
            child: Text("Cancel"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ).whenComplete(() {});



_uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((event) {
     
      _progress =
          event.bytesTransferred.toDouble() / event.totalBytes.toDouble();
/*THIS IS NOT UPDATING DIALOG*/
      setState(() {
        _progress = double.parse((_progress * 100).toStringAsFixed(2));
       
      });
});
```

Comment: Problem is that the call `setState` is not using the `StatefulBuilder`'s `setState` and is likely calling the `StatefulWidget`'s. You probably better to have an object implementing `ChangeNotifier` and listen for changes on that object in your dialog

Comment: Did u solve this?

Answer (score 1):

when your async data is updating show that data in stateless widget statefull widget did not update the whole widget ,use stateless widget to show the data  it update the state immediately,statefull widget set that data and stateless renders that data

Answer (score 0):

Use StatefulBuilder to use setState inside Dialog and update Widgets only inside of it.

```
 showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
          content: Text(contentText),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text("Cancel"),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  contentText = "Changed Content of Dialog";
                });
              },
              child: Text("Change"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: This is not working. i am updating from outside not from inside showDialog. On the inside showDialog i only want to show updated value

Answer (score -1):

when you update your state, that time you have to use stfullWidget. Eensure first, is it stfullWidget or not? if not then you should use stfullWidget insted of stlessWidget.

Comment: Both are stateful widgets